# Android Play Store Release Issue: APK HAS A PRIVACY POLICY​ BUT IT IS NOT ADEQUATE

Tags: android, react-native, google-play-console

[image: Play console app rejection email with reason]

Releases are being rejected while we've adhered to everything mentioned in the user data policy and updated the privacy policy in console too.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because there is no question here.

Answer (score 1):

You should have a URL to a Privacy Policy that explicitly mention that your are collecting users images.
Also you should mention this in the safety form.

Comment: How and where? We can already conclude form the message but how?